# Recent vs overall GPA in graduate school admissions

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, grades

This is an extension of my [previous question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/171313/ms-or-phd-with-publication-records). I'm applying to CS Ph.D. programs in the US. From my perspective, I have a strong profile (compared to my previous post, 1 more first-author paper and multiple non-first papers under review in top-tier venues), with the main low point being my CGPA (7.51/10.0). Evaluations by WES and other tools place this in a range of 3.2 to 3.5 out of 4.0. I wanted to know how this is viewed in comparison to my CGPA in my final two semesters, which are 8.0 and 9.25. Will these scores offset my overall lower GPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes, people will be more likely to consider recent grades as more indicative of what you are capable of. But in the individual case it is impossible to say. Another factor, of course, is which courses you have taken recently. If they are advanced courses in your major field and you do well it is *likely* to be a boost. But, again, the individual case trumps the general case.

The only way to absolutely measure your likelihood of success is to actually apply and see what results you get. And let  me say again as I did for the earlier question, cast a broad net, not a narrow one. And, again, admission in the US (which you indicated earlier) is broad based, with much more than GPA taken in to account. In particular, letters of recommendation are relatively important here.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! I'll be applying to a broad range of colleges with groups working in my area of interest.